# Sensitivity of observables to New Physics

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, beyond-the-standard-model

I am currently reading a PhD thesis on experimental particle physics and at some point the author talks about the sensitivity of a given observable $Q$ to New Physics (NP). The idea is that observables are in general expressed in terms of a sum of an amplitude $A_{SM}$ (coming from the Standard Model interaction Lagrangian) and an amplitude $A_{NP}$ coming from interactions beyond the SM:

$$Q\sim |A_{SM}+A_{NP}|^2.$$

For small $A_{SM}$ it is clear that the sensitivity of the observable to NP is greater and thus one is typically looking for NP in decays that are suppressed by the SM.

All this is fine, but I was wondering if someone could point out further specific readings clarifying the origin of the sum and the general idea discussed here, as the author does not cite any particular texts. Also, I would appreciate any further recommendations regarding the difference between direct and indirect searches for New Physics.

Answer (score 0):

The sum is using the simplest concepts of quantum mechanics: The wave functions, and the [wavefunction postulate,](https://www.google.com/search?q=postulates%20of%20quantum%20mechanics%20hyperphysics&oq=postulates%20of%20quantum&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j35i39j0l6.7224j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) i.e. that $Ψ^*Ψ$  of the wavefunction gives the probability of seeing a particle at (x,y,z,t). The square in the formula is the complex conjugate squared as wavefunctions are complex number quantities.

It is a simple estimate on how, if two mechanisms  happen at the same time, one could read the probability for the whole interaction. If one knows from the standard model  how much $A_{SM}$ is, the excess in the number of interactions seen will be $A_{NP}$ new physics, if it is statistically significant. It is a first order (mathematically) estimate .

I would like to add that **the whole experimental research programs of high energy physics aim at finding New Physics**, and extend the knowledge base

Roughly there are two methods,  one using accelerators relies on searching for deviations from the standard model, as above. The experiments done with large detectors and cosmic input are also looking for experimental signatures not in the standard model and are also open to effects that may be completely unexpected  (for example neutrino oscillations), and may find completely new physics.